# Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

The problem is, as stated:

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}$$
>   Of course, a and b are real numbers.

I tried implementing the trig identity:

$$\cos(ax)-\cos(bx) = -2\sin\frac{(ax-bx)}{2}\sin\frac{(ax+bx)}{2}$$

But that didn't really take me anywhere. 
In my book, similar problems were often solved this way but here that doesn't seem to work.

One obviously has to try and use the known limit to reduce this to a more easy limit:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned L'Hopitals Rule?

Comment: Yes, but this particular problem was part of the set that was supposed to be solved without using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity given in your question is useful for evaluating the limit: as $x\to 0$ we have
$$\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)} = -2\frac{\frac{\sin\frac{(ax-bx)}{2}}{x}\cdot \frac{\sin\frac{(ax+bx)}{2}}{x}}{\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}}\to -2\frac{\frac{a-b}{2}\cdot \frac{a+b}{2}}{1\cdot 1}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$
where we used the fact that for any real $\alpha$,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}=\alpha\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{(\alpha x)}=\alpha\cdot 1=\alpha.$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{\sin^2x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\cdot\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x^2}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x^2}\\&=\frac{b^2-a^2}2\end{align}since$$\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)=-\frac12(a^2-b^2)x^2+o(x^2).$$

Comment: I think your answer is a little wrong. Can you please check again?

Comment: How did you get that last identity?

Comment: Check again last step  L Hospital gives a factor 2 at the denominator

Comment: @JaideepKhare There was indeed an error, which I have corrected.

Comment: In your last line probably you are using expansion of $\cos (ax)$, but you forgot that $a$ will also be squared, along with $x$.

Comment: Yes, now it seems good! (+1)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $b^2-a^2 \over 2$?

Comment: @Lorenzo I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: And the little o notation? Thats a rigorous proof of a limit how exactly?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum It's just a matter of noticing that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(ax)-1+\frac{a^2}2x^2}{x^2}=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{x^2}\\=-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1- \cos(ax)}{x^2}+\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1- \cos(bx)}{x^2}=\frac{ b^2-a^2}{2}$$

Given that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1- \cos(x)}{x^2}=1/2$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{ \sin(x)}{x}=1. $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint For Finishing The Approach In The Question**
$$
\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}=2\frac{\sin\left(\frac{b-a}2\,x\right)}{\sin(x)}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{b+a}2\,x\right)}{\sin(x)}
$$

---

**Hint For Another Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}
&=\frac{1-\cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}-\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\frac1{1+\cos(bx)}\frac{\sin^2(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}-\frac1{1+\cos(ax)}\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{\sin^2(x)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track,

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos (ax)-\cos (bx)}{\sin^2 x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{-2 \sin \left(\frac{a+b}{2}x \right)\sin \left(\frac{a-b}{2}x \right)}{\sin^2 x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}-2\frac{\frac{\sin \left(\frac{a+b}{2}x \right)}{x}}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\frac{\frac{\sin \left(\frac{a-b}{2}x \right)}{x}}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}.$$

It should be obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use L' Hospital rule
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{-a\sin(ax) +b \sin(bx)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{-a^2\cos(ax) +b^2 \cos(bx)}{2\cos^2(x)-2\sin^2(x)}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$
Where we applied L'Hospital's rule twice

Comment: @farruhota ah yes, I didn’t notice that mistake

Answer (score 0):

i would write
$$\frac{-2\left(\sin x\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)\right)\sin\left(x\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\right)x^2\left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{4}\right)}{x\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right) x\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\sin^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe this approach is simpler: since $1-\cos(cx)=2\sin^2\frac{cx}{2}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(dx)}{\sin(x)}=d$,

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{\sin^2(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{bx}{2}-2\sin^2\frac{ax}{2}}{\sin^2(x)}=2\left[\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\right]=\color{blue}{\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

From the [Taylor series of $\sin(x),\cos(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions) and using [$O$-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), we know that, for $x\to 0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin x &=&x+O\left( x^{3}\right)  \\
\cos x &=&1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+O\left( x^{3}\right). 
\end{eqnarray*}

Then 
$$
\sin ^{2}x=x^{2}+O\left( x^{4}\right) 
$$
and 
$$
\frac{\cos ax-\cos bx}{\sin ^{2}x}=\frac{\left( -\frac{1}{2}a^{2}+\frac{1}{2}
b^{2}\right) x^{2}+O\left( x^{3}\right) }{x^{2}+O\left( x^{4}\right) }.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos ax-\cos bx}{\sin ^{2}x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}
\frac{x^{2}\left( -\frac{1}{2}a^{2}+\frac{1}{2}b^{2}\right) }{x^{2}}=\frac{1
}{2}b^{2}-\frac{1}{2}a^{2}.
$$